# Jsrender IE 8 (Internet explorer)

Tags: internet-explorer, jsrender, ie8-browser-mode

I found jsrender a very simple option as a JS template engine.

I couldn't find which browsers does it support. Does it support IE 8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it supports IE8 and later, as well as current Chrome Firefox and Safari browsers.